# nuxt-i18n Strategy:no_prefix

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm trying to use nuxt-i18n to get internationalization for my application, the following are the nuxt-i18n configs and it works fine, but when I want to use strategy: 'no_prefix' it gives errors ... not sure what to do, please suggest.

```
i18n: {
    //strategy: 'no_prefix',
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: [
      {
        code: 'en',
        name: 'English',
        iso: 'en-US',
        file: 'english.js'
      },
      {
        code: 'hi',
        name: 'Hindi',
        file: 'hindi.js'
      }
    ],
    lazy: true,
    langDir: 'static/locales/'
  },
```

https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/routing.html#strategy

> WARN  [nuxt-i18n] Passing non-current locale to switchLocalePath is
>   unsupported when using no_prefix strategy
>   19:39:39
>
> WARN  [nuxt-i18n] Passing non-current locale to localePath is
>   unsupported when using no_prefix strategy
>   19:39:39

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the `no_prefix` strategy you won't get the benefit for using the `path` functions that is provided by the module. For example those 2 `switchLocalePath` & `localePath` is not supported when using `no_prefix`. As the docs say:

```
This implies that you have to rely on browser & cookie detection, and implement locale switches by calling the i18n API.
```

So you should use the APIs that are provided by the module in order to change the locale. One of example in my project is when user want's to change a locale I added a handler and change the locale by calling this:

`this.$i18n.setLocale('en')`

or

`root.$i18n.setLocale(langCode)` (if using the composition-api)

Comment: `this.$18n` is just not available when creating a method. at least in my case... i went with `@click="$i18n.setLocale('en')"`

Comment: @AndréKelling if you are accesing within `template` then `this` it's not accessible.

Comment: @AndréKelling `valid1() { return this.$i18n.setLocale('en') }` is ok, `valid2: function () { return this.$i18n.setLocale('en') }` works too, but `invalid: () => this.$i18n.setLocale('en')` won't work.

Comment: @sixty-nine using `this` inside arrow functions might cause confusion

Comment: @praburangki that's why the third function is called invalid :)